# Call to fetch returning 401

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

If I run the following:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token',{mode: 'no-cors'}).
then(response=>response)
```

from within my webapp hosted via localhost:11111 I get a 401 error.

However if I open a tab in the same browser and enter http://localhost:8080/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token then I get a 200 response.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is working via curl:

curl 'http://localhost:8080/gui/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token'    -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=CviS9IK8pcsqADdP-m0MRXX_AvUqfzjJPwk1Yytf.ee16d0a01ad5'

So I need to provide a cookie

Comment: So are you asking how to provide a cookie via `fetch`, or have you solved your issue now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To automatically send cookies for the current domain, the credentials option must be provided:

```
fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

Comment: fetch('/users', {
  credentials: 'include'
})
worked for me.